# Post and Get JSON via Python

Tags: jquery, json

A Topic should be created by a user:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="topic">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Topic">
</form>
```

The topic which is created by the user should post to my local `topic.json` file after the user push the submit topic button.
My  `topic.json` file is in /dekstop/test/data/topic.json path which you can find my html too.

```
topic = '[{"name" : "}]';
```

Every time when a user creates a new topic and push the submit button. My json file should grow.

On my second `html` Ii would like to parse my `topic.json` file under

```
<div>here you see my topic</div>
```

I am using Python 3.3 and I am working with cherrypy. 
Can anybody show me how I can do this please.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know Python, but I'm sure you can get that part working by yourself.

To get the JSON data and add to it:

```
$.getJSON("./data/topic.json", function(data) {
  var newTopic = {name:'Jessica Alba'};
  data.push(newTopic);      
});
```

To post the updated JSON back to your server:

```
$.post('./data/save-json.php', {
    newData: $.param(data)
}, function(response){
    // do something with response
});
```

In PHP, I would something like this:

```
$data = $_POST['newData'];
file_put_contents('topic.json', json_encode($data));
```

Comment: $.post('http://example.com/saveJson.php'
i just want to use it without php.

i have a own localhost:8080 or what does $.post('http://example.com/saveJson.php' means?

Comment: @user5551775: This is the problem when you ask questions about something you have no knowledge about. I suggest you learn some basics before asking people to code your project for you. I have given you enough here to take away and get something working. I'm out, good luck.